# How to build a msi with electron?

Tags: angularjs, windows-installer, electron

I have a project in angularjs and electron, and I would like to run it on Windows 8, 8.1 or 10,

I need to build a msi to install my app on ProgramFiles folder, and create a desktop link.

When I install a new version on this app, I need to uninstall the old version in ProgramFiles and install the new one.

I tried electron-packager with electron-winstaller but the msi file generates an Installer on ProgramFiles which install on AppData.

[Screenshot with ProgramFiles and AppData folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oARiR.png)

What solutions would you suggest ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Is there a reason why you need it to install in the `ProgramFiles` folder?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I have already posted a solution for electron projects wanting to utilize Wix for MSI deployment.  Hope this helps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46474978/3946706